# How to place an ai file behind photoshop layer CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, layers

I'm working with Photoshop and AI files, both of which are pretty new to me. When placing an AI file on my image, it creates a layer just as I would expect. However, the layer shows up in front of all other layers, even when I place it at the bottom of the list. I'm assuming there's some sort of adjustment I need to make to the layer but I have no idea what it is. Anyone know how to push the ai file to the background?

Comment: If you have already moved your ai file/smart object layer to the bottom of the layer stack, you might have transparency or blending modes turned on on the upper layers, which would allow you to "see through" those layers to your ai file.

Comment: note that most layers in photoshop are transparent by default unless you flood fill them etc.

Comment: @Jeremiah did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Move the layer containing the smart object to the bottom of the layer stack in Photoshop. Just click it and drag.

Comment: That's the way that I thought it should work, but it's not working. It always stays at the front.

Comment: That works with other ai files, but they seem to ignore the other layers.

Comment: All I can suggest is that perhaps the blending mode of other layers is allowing the Smart Object to show through.